# Parsing database Firebase data android

Tags: android, parsing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I spend many time for understand how parsing data from firebase database. I have database structure like this:

```
> taskmanager-df376
>> users
>>> 55lYbtrPZNPIo9QvQhmpMPIKiVB3
>>>> d9dd91ab-26ec-4f19-9e2e-0489c7410d0d
>>>>> description: "123"
>>>>> name : "hello"
>>>> e989a6f1-2be4-4b4c-870b-f4ec5074991b
>>>>> description: "2112"
>>>>> name : "1221"
```

Below I try parsing data:

```
 mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.

        try{
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child("users").getChildren()) {

                HashMap<String,Notes> messageMap = (HashMap<String, Notes>) postSnapshot.getValue();
                Collection<Notes> messageItems = messageMap.values() ;

                ArrayList<Notes> copy = new ArrayList<Notes>(messageItems);
                // next ???
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.e("error", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: fyi: you can get your actual JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: What does your `Notes` class look like?

Answer (score 0):

To get the data that coresponds to your database structure, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("users").child("55lYbtrPZNPIo9QvQhmpMPIKiVB3");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", description + " / " + name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
123 / hello
2112 / 1221
```